# JsonFormat alterando data em uma requisição get

Tags: java, json, spring, data, spring-boot

Tenho um web service em java utilizando Spring Boot, em uma classe tenho um atributo do tipo date e uso o JsonFormat para formatar a data e poder converter no lado cliente, usando Gson. Porém, mesmo definindo o locale para o zona do Brasil, que seria o UTC-03, ele converte para três horas a mais, tornando a data diferente. Como resolver esse problema?

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", locale = "UTC-03")
private Date date;
```

Answer (score 3):

> Porém, mesmo definindo o locale para o zona do Brasil, que seria o UTC-03

Na verdade, o locale tem outro [significado](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html).

Tente mudar a anotação para definir o [timezone](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html#timezone()):

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", timezone="GMT-3")
private Date date;
```

Comment: Eu já havia tentando essa abordagem, mas não deu certo. Porém, dessa vez deu. Não faço ideia do que pode ter acontecido..

Comment: Quando coloco a plicação no Tomcat, continua aumentando 3 horas, mesmo com o timezone setado.

Comment: Marcelo, conseguiu resolver? Estou com o mesmo problema.

Comment: Opa... usando o timezone resolveu o meu problema! Obrigado!